# How to devide data to groups in excel?

Tags: excel

I have numerical column and should add another column by devided to groups first column.
first column look like this:

```
1234
13214
231
```

And I should get this column:

```
1000 - 2000
10000-50000
0-500
```

I know I can use the formula with "if", but it is too long formula because I need devide to a lot of groups.
how can I do this without "if"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `if` you can always use a pivot table and the 'group' functionality:

https://trumpexcel.com/group-numbers-in-pivot-table/

The only issue is you need to dump the data, do the group and pull it back